# Supertable bilingual (multi-site)

Tags: craft3, multi-site, plugin-supertable

I want to save a supertable with different infos on two different siteId of an entry. It works fine with all the other fields i'm using: the value is saved separately to each different language. But with the supertable, the info is saved, but it overrides both languages with the new info.. Is there a parameter we need to add or something?
I'm using this:

```
$field = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldByHandle($handle);
    $blockTypes = SuperTable::$plugin->getService()->getBlockTypesByFieldId($field->id);
    $blockType = $blockTypes[0];

    $superTableData['new1'] = [
        'type' => $blockType->id,
        'enabled' => true,
        'fields' => [
           'field1' => 'value',
           'field2' => 'value',
         ]
    ];
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, site association for elements is controlled using the `$siteId` property. Try this:

```php
$superTableData['new1'] = [
    'type' => $blockType->id,
    'enabled' => true,
    'siteId' => 123, // replace with your site ID
    'fields' => [
       'field1' => 'value',
       'field2' => 'value',
    ]
];
```

Comment: yeah I tried, it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like the short answer is: you can't.

First you have to create the entry and superTable to the default site and it copies the data to every site.

Then you need to update the entry WITH siteId of other site and update the supertable.

That's the way that worked for me!